# Row level security does not work for table owner

Tags: postgresql, row-level-security

I have a table, `customer` on which I did the following:

```
ALTER TABLE customer FORCE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;
CREATE POLICY customer_rls ON  customer USING (false);
```

However, doing `SELECT * FROM customer` still returns all the rows.

The current role is `myrole`

```
\dg myrole
           List of roles
 Role name | Attributes | Member of
-----------+------------+-----------
 my_role   |            | {}
```

As you can see it's not a superuser and it RLS isn't disabled on it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to enable row level security for the table.

```
ALTER TABLE customer enable ROW LEVEL SECURITY;
```

`force` only makes sure that RLS is applied if enabled, it does not enable RLS on the table.

Online example: https://rextester.com/TCLZ82421

Comment: Yup. That was it. I'd say the docs could use some work in explaining this better. Thank you very much!